# Can I also estimate the factor values of the latent variable with parcels (parcelAllocation function + lavaan.mi) or do I use the raw data of items?

Tags: r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

The lavPredict function only accepts lavaan objects, but not lavaan.mi objects. However, these are used in the parcelAllocation function.

Can I still determine the factor values on the basis of the parcels or do I simply use the SEM model with the original items and save it as a fit and pass it to the lavPredict function?

With the help of the estimated factor values, I would like to check the assumptions of linearity and (no) outliers.

Or would the correct order be more like this: I calculate the factor values of the latent variables using the original items, check the linearity and outliers and only then I do the parceling and concentrate on the model fit? Because if the assumptions are not given, I am not allowed to take the further steps such as parceling?

What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

> lavPredict function only accepts lavaan objects, but not lavaan.mi objects

If you want to conduct factor-score regression, you should account for their uncertainty by sampling a distribution of plausible values rather than treating a single point estimate (per person) as known data.  The `semTools::plausibleValues()` function does accept `lavaan.mi` objects, and will return `nDraws=` plausible-values samples per imputation.  For example, if you have 20 imputations of missing data, then you can set `nDraws=5` plausible values, which will result in 5*20=100 imputed data sets that you can analyze using factor-score regression.  Pooled *SE*s and test statistics will account or all sources of uncertainty (complete-data sampling error, missing-data sampling error, and uncertainty of factor-score estimates).

> used in the parcelAllocation function

If you set the same parcelAllocation(..., `iseed=`) within each imputation, then you will apply the same random-allocation patterns to each imputation.  You can still use `plausibleValues()`, in which case pooled *SE*s and tests will also account for random-allocation uncertainty.  But you are going to start compounding the number of data sets you analyze (product of the numbers of imputations, plausible-value samples, and random allocations), so be prepared to wait longer for `lavaan.mi()` results.

> Can I still determine the factor values on the basis of the parcels?

The factor-score estimates will (likely) be less stable with fewer indicators.  Even if those parceled indicators have proportionally less measurement error, that does not make up for the increased factor indeterminacy of fewer parcels than items.

https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-019-09677-2

https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2018.1535420

> With the help of the estimated factor values, I would like to check the assumptions of linearity and (no) outliers

That is unlikely to help.  Factor scores are estimated on the assumption of linearity, so any actual nonlinearity in their effects on indicators would be dampened by that assumption.

If you identify outliers on the observed indicators, then you could use `regsem`, but that package only applies to complete data. Alternatively, you could use MCMC estimation and specify a *t* rather than normal distribution for the factor scores.  A *t* distribution with small *df* has been shown to be more robust because it has heavier tails.

[https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chuanhai/docs/tFA.pdf](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Echuanhai/docs/tFA.pdf)

Unfortunately, `blavaan` does not yet allow specification of custom priors for factor scores using `target = "stanclassic"`, so you would have to code your model manually in Stan or JAGS/BUGS to apply this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

(1) I did not want to test the linearity between latent variables and indicators. I wanted to test the linearity between variables in my path model via scatter plots. 

I can use the estimated factor values for this, can't I? 

(2) I wanted to find out the outliers as follows, for each equation of the path model:

reg.fit.dv1 <- lm(data= df, Manifest variable ~ estimated factor value_LV1 + estimated factor value_LV2). ols_plot_resid_lev(reg.fit.dv1). Would this be a possible way?

Comment: You *can*, but see my answer about the linearity assumption not being designed to preserve those features.

Comment: Ah okay, as soon as I have factorvalues estimated, non-linear influences are "eliminated" so that these are also not evident between the variables in a path model. 

Do you know of a good website where the testing of the assumptions of a SEM in R-Studio has been implemented as an example. I usually find information on statistical prerequisites/assumptions but rarely with practical implementation in R.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/package=influence.SEM